# get_headers is not following redirects - why not?

Tags: php, http-headers

I need to retrieve the *final* set of headers from a site after all redirects have been followed.  According to comments in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), get_headers is supposed to follow redirects.  However, I tested at phpfiddle.org and also on my own server using the url "http://microsoft.com".  (PHP 5.x)

```
$r = get_headers('http://microsoft.com', 0);
    var_dump($r);
```

Results:

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  [2]=>
  string(35) "Location: http://www.microsoft.com/"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
  [4]=>
  string(21) "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET"
  [5]=>
  string(35) "Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 19:55:58 GMT"
  [6]=>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [7]=>
  string(19) "Content-Length: 148"
  [8]=>
  string(15) "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
  [9]=>
  string(14) "Server: Apache"
  [10]=>
  string(51) "ETag: "6082151bd56ea922e1357f5896a90d0a:1425454794""
  [11]=>
  string(44) "Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 07:39:54 GMT"
  [12]=>
  string(20) "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
  [13]=>
  string(20) "Content-Length: 1020"
  [14]=>
  string(23) "Content-Type: text/html"
  [15]=>
  string(35) "Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 19:55:59 GMT"
  [16]=>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [17]=>
  string(6) "X-N: S"
}
```

Any idea why this doesn't work, and how to make it work?

I know it's not fully following the redirects, because if you type in the URL: http://microsoft.com, you end up at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us.  And you can see the headers don't include a redirect to here.

The reason I need this to work: I need to determine if the final page has the X-Frame-Options header set.  Both the http://microsoft.com and http://www.microsoft.com/ pages do not have this header, but the http://www.microsoft.com/en-us page returns the X-Frame-Options header, preventing the page from being loaded in an iframe.

I need to determine if the page in question can be loaded in an iframe by examining this header, then if not, I need to redirect the user to the destination instead of showing the page in an iframe.

Thanks

Comment: `get_headers` does follow redirections. Your result shows that. After the first redirect it gets a HTTP 200 response from the server. So everything is working as expected.

Comment: So why didn't it redirect over to the final http://microsoft.com/en-us page?

Comment: Because Microsoft didn't tell the client to redirect to `microsoft.com/en-us`, simple as that.

Comment: I see... so that second redirect is possibly based on another factor not present in the PHP request, and possibly browser-based?

Comment: So my ultimate goal to see the X-Frame-Options header, as it would be seen by the end user, is probably impossible?

Comment: Maybe. You could try sending the header `Accept-Language` along the request to see if the redirections are based on browser language. cURL is an option to test that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100709/discussion-between-ryan-griggs-and-charlotte-dunois).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_header` *does* follow redirects. When you examine your dumped headers carefully, you'll notice that the array contains *two* sets of response headers:

That's the first one:

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  [2]=>
  string(35) "Location: http://www.microsoft.com/"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
  [4]=>
  string(21) "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET"
  [5]=>
  string(35) "Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 19:55:58 GMT"
  [6]=>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [7]=>
  string(19) "Content-Length: 148"
```

And the second:

```
  [8]=>
  string(15) "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
  [9]=>
  string(14) "Server: Apache"
  [10]=>
  string(51) "ETag: "6082151bd56ea922e1357f5896a90d0a:1425454794""
  [11]=>
  string(44) "Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 07:39:54 GMT"
  [12]=>
  string(20) "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
  [13]=>
  string(20) "Content-Length: 1020"
  [14]=>
  string(23) "Content-Type: text/html"
  [15]=>
  string(35) "Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 19:55:59 GMT"
  [16]=>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [17]=>
  string(6) "X-N: S"
}
```

The final redirection from http://www.microsoft.com to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us is probably language specific and is dependent on the `Accept-Language` request header (when opening the same URL in my browser, I end up at http://www.microsoft.com/de-de).

Comment: I wonder how they decide what language to redirect? is it based on IP address, browser settings, etc?

Comment: As I said: The `Accept-Language` header. Your browser sends that.